# How to print HTML and to highlight some tags in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm making the program using PyQt5. One of functions is printing HTML with highlight of some tags by different colours. Every new string is processed and added to text using .append method. I need to print clear HTML, that's way class QTextEdit is not suitable. To solve this problem, one needs to use QPlainTextEdit. But I got a new problem. Now I can't use tags `<font>` to appoint colour to certain tag. Shielding of tags in class QTextEdit is not good idea. Also, I can't appoint colour to whole field.
How can I solve this problem?
P.S. Sorry for mistakes in my English. You can tell me about them.

Comment: Use [QTextCursor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcursor.html) to add the strings one by one. Then you can use [QTextCharFormat](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcharformat.html) to change the formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to make a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

The comment section already has a good way of doing it, and here is another way.

You can just `import html` and use html.escape(text). This way you can escape part of the html code that are supposed to be literal strings while keeping other html working. This way you can also keep using QTextEdit.

Here's a quick example:

what I did was:

```
a = html.escape("<font size=\"3\" color=\"red\">This is some text!</font>")
self.append("<a href=\"\" style=\"color:#FF0000\">"+a+"</a>")
```

and this is the result.

[image: quick example]